# Run only acceptance test in Mocha

Tags: ember.js, mocha.js

Is there a way to run just a given acceptance test? We have a bunch of integration tests and I just want to see how my acceptance test runs. From the command line, I'm using ember test --serve, but I'd like to run just this specific test. All my tests are in one file and I only want to run those.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, I found it.

```
ember test --server --filter="my_test_name"
```